# How to check a double's bit pattern is 0x0 in a C++11 constexpr?

Tags: c++, casting, c++11, floating-point, constexpr

I want to check that a given double/float variable has the actual bit pattern 0x0. Don't ask why, it's used in a function in Qt (`qIsNull()`) that I'd like to be `constexpr`.

The original code used a union:

```
union { double d; int64_t i; } u;
u.d = d;
return u.i == 0;
```

This doesn't work as a `constexpr` of course.

The next try was with `reinterpret_cast`:

```
return *reinterpret_cast<int64_t*>(&d) == 0;
```

But while that works as a `constexpr` in GCC 4.7, it fails (rightfully, b/c of pointer manipulation) in Clang 3.1.

The final idea was to go Alexandrescuesque and do this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
union Converter {
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;
    explicit constexpr Converter( T1 t1 ) : t1(t1) {}
    constexpr operator T2() const { return t2; }
};

// in qIsNull():
return Converter<double,int64_t>(d);
```

But that's not clever enough for Clang, either:

```
note: read of member 't2' of union with active member 't1' is not allowed in a constant expression
constexpr operator T2() const { return t2; }
                                       ^
```

Does anyone else have a good idea?

Comment: I guess there are other bit patterns that also represent a floating point 0, that you don't want to find?

Comment: There are exactly two bit patterns that represent 0. They are 000...000 and 100...000. The first bit is the sign bit. The second bit pattern is sometimes referred to as "negative zero".

Comment: Perhaps `return d == 0 && 1/d > 0;`? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero#Comparisons)

Comment: `Don't ask why` Don't tell me what to do

Comment: @Lightness: don't tell Marc what not to do ;-p

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is prohibited to appear in constant expressions. But what if you attempt `static_cast<const int64_t*>(static_cast<const void*>(&d))` instead?

Comment: @LucDanton: I don't think it's `reinterpret_cast` vs. `static_cast` that's the issue, at least Clang rejects both. I guess it doesn't like taking the address. After all, how could it compute that at compile-time?

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan: cf. the original code. It tests for a literal 0x0 bitpattern, not FP-equals-zero. I do wonder why they're so keen on skipping -0, but as a first approximation, I want to maintain behavioural compatibility while turning that thing `constexpr`...

Comment: @MarcMutz-mmutz Addressof is fine as a constant expression. It even appears in the (non-normative) examples: `constexpr const int* addr(const int& ir) { return &ir; } // OK`. `reinterpret_cast`, on the other hand, is *explicitly* forbidden. So obviously that's going to be a roadblock.

Answer (score 6):

> I want to check that a given double/float variable has the actual bit pattern 0x0

But if it's `constexpr` then it's not checking any *variable*, it's checking the *value* that this variable is statically determined to hold. That's why you aren't supposed to pull pointer and union tricks, "officially" there isn't any memory to point at.

If you can persuade your implementation to do non-trapping IEEE division-by-zero, then you could do something like:

```
return (d == 0) && (1 / d > 0)
```

Only `+/-0` are equal to 0. `1/-0` is `-Inf`, which isn't greater than 0. `1/+0` is `+Inf`, which is. But I don't know how to make that non-trapping arithmetic happen.

Comment: Isn't the implementation usually non-trapping by default?

Comment: @Christian: on GCC with vanilla command-line options I get a floating point error if I divide by zero.

Comment: Aha, Ok. By the way, if I read correctly you can actually use `feholdecxept` from `<cfenv>` (C++11/C99) to enter non-trapping mode. And since he uses C++11, this might be a nice addition to your answer (but don't forget `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON` in this case).

Comment: Ah forget my comment, I forgot were talking about compile-time here.

Comment: Division by zero renders an expression non-constant in C++11.

Answer (score 5):

It seems both clang++ 3.0 and g++ 4.7 (but not 4.6) treats `std::signbit` as `constexpr`.

```
return x == 0 && std::signbit(x) == 0;
```

Comment: Clang 3.0 doesn't implement `constexpr`? Anyway [c.math]/11 of C++11 clearly states that `std::signbit` isn't `constexpr` :(

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to look at the underlying bit pattern of a `double` from within a constant expression. There was a defect in the C++11 standard which allowed such inspection by casting via a `void*`, but that was addressed by [C++ core issue 1312](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1312).

As "proof", clang's `constexpr` implementation (which is considered to be complete) has no mechanism for extracting the representation of a constant `double` value (other than via non-standard vector operations, and even then there is currently no way to inspect the result).

As others have suggested, if you know you will be targeting a platform which uses IEEE-754 floating point, `0x0` corresponds to the value positive zero. I believe the only way to detect this, that works inside a constant expression in both clang and g++, is to use `__builtin_copysign`:

```
constexpr bool isPosZero(double d) {
  return d == 0.0 && __builtin_copysign(1.0, d) == 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In c++20 one can use constexpr bit_cast, and so the check for the unsigned zero can be done like this:

std::bit_cast<uint64_t, double>(d) == 0